# Delete Account button missing when trying to delete XP users?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete a user in Windows XP, can’t find delete button or it’s not showing](https://superuser.com/questions/160318/delete-a-user-in-windows-xp-cant-find-delete-button-or-its-not-showing)

When I'm logged in as Administrator and I try to delete a users account. The delete account link is just gone. How can I get it back?

System specs
-Win XP pro SP2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Do you see the account you wish to delete (like above)? If so then right click on the account you wish to delete and select Delete

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the last administrator account, if that's the problem.

Comment: There are 2 administrator accounts, I only need to delete the second one, when logged in with the first one

Comment: 2 Admin Accounts available. I need that link back

Comment: Why didn't you answer Systech? Do you mean that the "Delete" entry doesn't appear in the context menu of this user? Does it appear for any other user, and especially the other administrator?