# Delete a user in Windows XP, can't find delete button or it's not showing

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

I added a test account to my virtual XP machine the other week and now I want to remove it.

The delete user button is not visible on their page. On the user accounts page the tooltip says that clicking on the user will allow me to delete it - but there is no button for this.

I have the machine setup to do an auto-logon - perhaps that removes the delete facility. But it logs on as my usual (other) account so you would think that it should not affect things.

Is there a permission I need to turn on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this command line

```
net user yourUserNameHere /DELETE
```

For example, if your test username is "ABCD" you'd run this:

```
net user ABCD /DELETE
```

Make sure you're logged on as an administrator of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you're logged on as an admin and that the other account is not logged on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try a different GUI, right-click on `My Computer` and select `Manage`.  In the `Computer Management` window select `Local Users and Groups > Users`.  In that view, right-click the User and select `Delete`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBScript:

```
strComputer = "." : strUsername = "USERNAME"
GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer).Delete "user", strUsername
```